# copy decimal number value to a compponent

Tags: javascript, xpages

```
var valT = @TextToNumber("123,43"); 
getComponent("ValRamasa").setValue(valT);
```

The value returned is `0.` and the component `ValRamasa` :

```
<xp:inputText id="ValRamasa" disabled="true">
        <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber type="number"
                    maxFractionDigits="2" locale="ro">

               </xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
    < xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{viewScope.field_2[index]}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:inputText>
```

The converter is setted to my locale such that: `,` is the decimal separator and `.` is the thousand separator.

If I try  `var valT = @TextToNumber("123.43");` => `123,43`.

Why I tried the above example? I have an input field ( whith `locale="ro"` ) where the user can add some number ( with `,` as the decimal separator ), and with this value I want to do some math calculations, but I noticed the above issue occurs.

My calculations ( I'm using a repeat control ):

```
    var number = getComponent("inputText11").getValue();
    var procent = getComponent("inputText19").getValue();

        for(var i = 0;i<=index ;i++){
// ****** val - is the 'problem' value **** IF val = integer => it works / IF val = decimal ( with , as decimal separator ) => IT don't works 
        var val = viewScope.field_1[i]; 
/* <xp:inputText id="inputText23">
         <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{viewScope.field_1[index]}]]></xp:this.value>
                 <xp:this.converter>
                            <xp:convertNumber type="number" locale="ro" maxFractionDigits="2">
                            </xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:inputText>*/

        //val = val.replace(",",".");
        val = @TextToNumber(val);

        //number = Number(number) - Number(val);
        number -= val;
        var garantie = procent*val/100;

        }

        //var valT = @TextToNumber("123.43"); 
        getComponent("ValRamasa").setValue(number);
        getComponent("ValGarantie").setValue(garantie);
```

Comment: TextToNumber is for sure not your problem here. The component you deal with is of type number, meaning, that it is STORED as a number -regardless of any "display" properties. For sure you have an implicit text- conversion somewhere and try to convert this text back: Then the locale settings will be ignored and an error will raise. Post the code for your CALCULATION, as THERE is the error. TextToNumber works as designed...

Comment: Where do the values in "viewScope.field_1" come from? I guess, that  there is "Text" in these variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TextToNumber is for sure not your problem here.

The component you deal with is of type number, meaning, that it is STORED as a number -regardless of any "display" properties.

For sure you have an implicit text- conversion somewhere and try to convert this text back:

Then the locale settings will be ignored and an error will raise.

In your posted code for the calculation, there is also no obvious error.

But: where do the values in "viewScope.field_1" come from? I guess, that there is "Text" in these variables, that causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

@TextToNumber does not follow any locale settings as this is a program language. To convert a number into text your number must follow the guidelines of the language, in this case you have to use the colon . in your number as decimal separator. If you'd use this formula e.g. in a view column you'll get an error message - try it!
The converter of a field is used to convert and accept the typed in value.

Comment: I instructed the users to use , as the decimal separator considering the fact that in this region we type 241,94 and not 241.94 . This is the reason I used locale = "ro" for my inputFields having type = "number".

Comment: So, if I have an inputField with locale="ro", and the users type 1546,55 ( for example ) . There is a button when clicking it some math calculus take place. So, I need firstly to convert this 1.546,55 to 1,546.55 and having the last value for the math calculations?

Comment: NO, you don't need any conversion: Internally this is stored as number and just presented to the user with dot and comma... Just do your maths on the number and everything will work.

Comment: Oliver and Torsten are correct. A converter with max decimal places as 2 and locale="ro" just means take this back-end stored number, convert it to a string and display using the specific locale settings for "ro"; and when you receive input, take the submitted value, convert back from the specific locale settings of "ro" and remove any more than 2 decimal places. Unless you're using getComponent().getSubmittedValue(), you do not need to code for the locale.